# Dynamic image display based up on two values from database

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am currently trying to display images dynamically based on two values being returned from the database I am querying. These values are:

1. imageName = img1
2. fileType = jpg

I have a simple version which pulls out the correct data displaying the image and fileType correctly using a php echo command. However, when I try adding the same variables to a html img tag it doesn't work?

I am wanting the end result to be something like the following:

```
echo "    <img src=\"images/profile/" .  $info['imageName'] . "." .  $info['fileType'] . \" width=\"100\" height=\"100\">\n";
```

Any known how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be due to the missing quotation marks. Try this:

```
echo "    <img src=\"images/profile/" .  $info['imageName'] . "." .  $info['fileType'] . "\" width=\"100\" height=\"100\">\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your code(missing `"`).

```
echo "    <img src=\"images/profile/" .  $info['imageName'] . "." .  $info['fileType'] . "\" width=\"100\" height=\"100\">\n";
//                                                                                       ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
<img src="images/profile/<?php echo $info['imageName'];?>.<?php echo $info['fileType'];?>" ... >
```

or

```
<?php
  $image_name = $info['imageName'];
  $image_type = $info['fileType'];
?>

<img src="images/profile/<?php echo $image_name?>.<?php echo $image_type;?>" ... >
```